# Getting OAuth token rejected when trying use the v2 API Explorer for Intuit IPP for QBD

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I logged into the API explorer and authorized my dummy company file here:  http://idsapiexplorer.cloudapp.net/V2QBD#api

It is indicating everything is ok:

[image]

When I try to make a request, I keep getting the following response:
[image]

Here is the `ErrorDesc`:

```
<ErrorDesc>message=Exception authenticating OAuth; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401; source=OAuthStrategy; oauth_problem=token_rejected; cause=net.oauth.OAuthProblemException: token_rejected</ErrorDesc>
```

I'm guessing I'm probably not using this correctly.  Is there any more documentation I can read to learn?  Or is there an actual problem happening that is causing this error?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try disconnecting and then authorizing again to get a new Access Token and Secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means the token was not found, expired or invalid.
I would try refreshing your access token and you should be all set.

thanks
Jarred

Comment: I pretty sure I did that, but maybe not.  Thanks!  Working now.